# Python: Get the absolute xpath of an element inside the page

Tags: python, html, xpath

From [this page](http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/voelske/11voelske.html) (and some other like this) I need to get the absolute xpath for each author at the bottom of the page. The number of the authors is different from page to page.
With the xpath `//p[@class="blue"]/b/text()` i am able to retrieve all the authors names but i need the exact xpath for each of them (without classes or IDs).

I need to obtain this `form_table3_tr_td_table5_tr_td_table1_tr_td2_table1_tr_td2_p_b_text()` for the first author, `form_table3_tr_td_table5_tr_td_table1_tr_td2_table2_tr_td2_p_b_text()`for the 2nd ecc.

EDIT:
Here is the code I use to retrieve a list with the names of the authors:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/voelske/11voelske.html"
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
authors=tree.xpath('//p[@class="blue"]/b/text()')
```

Comment: Do you have to use XPath here or could you try something like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: Yes,only xpath unfortunately.

Comment: What framework / Python library are you working with? Please show the Python code you are using.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I am using lxml and requests modules. I've edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this xpath:

```
//table[1]/tbody/tr/td/p[@class='blue']/b
```

if you change the [1] in [2] ... [3], you'll be able to get all the absolutes xpath

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This may be a good solution but i have to analize not just that page but also others from the same website and the number of the authors is not the same (i've edited the question). I need a more generic solution for my purpose.